# Using GCC Undefined Behavior Sanitizer

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-behavior, undefined-reference, ubsan

Today I have read [an article](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/) about **GCC Undefined Behavior Sanitizer (ubsan)**. However, when I follow steps there (add `-fsanitize=undefined` to my code), the compiler (GCC 4.9.2 on Ubuntu 15.04) says that some references are not defined:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Project (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj/Debug/App.o||In function `App::OnInit()':|
/home/ilya/Project/App.cpp|31|undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch'|
/home/ilya/Project/App.cpp|31|undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_load_invalid_value'|
...
obj/Debug/App.o||In function `wxObjectEventFunctor::operator()(wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)':|
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/event.h|3757|undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_add_overflow'|
obj/Debug/App.o||In function `std::_Vector_base<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >::~_Vector_base()':|
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h|161|undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_sub_overflow'|
...
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 23 second(s)) ===|
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Give this a try. From a comment on the page you linked to: "Note, libubsan may not be installed on your system by default. On fedora 21+ install as follows: `yum install libubsan`"

Comment: I have installed `libubsan0` and `lib64ubsan0`, but nothing changed. Maybe I should link it somehow?

Comment: Yes, I've added a -lubsan option, and it worked! (^_^)

Answer (score 26):

The article you cited, as seen at [its new home](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/), already provides the answer, but you didn't notice it :-) With bold mine:

> GCC recently (version 4.9) gained *Undefined Behavior Sanitizer* (ubsan), a run-time checker for the C and C++ languages. In order to check your program with ubsan, compile **and link** the program with `-fsanitize=undefined` option.

I think the correct way to solve this is not to manually link with `ubsan`, but instead to simply also pass `-fsanitize=undefined` to the linker, not just the compiler. Sure, reinventing the wheel might work for you, but it's not needed, and there might be a reason that there is a specific linker flag for this, instead.

Certainly, that works: I was suddenly getting piles of undefined reference errors and, after giving up and just not using it for months, [yugr's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336475/2757035) pointed me in the right direction: I was only passing `-fsanitize=undefined` to `meson.add_project_arguments()`, but those only go to the compiler; I also needed to pass it to `meson.add_project_link_arguments()`. After adding that, the errors are gone, and the program links.

Comment: It's been a general rule for ages that *all* compilation flags should be passed in the link phase and the compiler/linker driver will ignore any that are not needed, so if meson does not just pass everything from project arguments to project link arguments, I'd tend to call it a bug.

Comment: @JanHudec You might want to search Meson's issue tracker for such a bug then, or file it if there isn't one ;-) What I said is straight out of [Meson's reference manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html). Specifically, `add_project_arguments()` is documented in terms of `add_global_arguments()`, which "_Adds the positional arguments to the compiler command line._" - whereas `add_global_link_arguments()` and `add_project_link_arguments()` are documented as "_Like `add_global|project_arguments` but the arguments are passed to the linker._" - and tbh I have no opinion on it either way

Comment: Use `b_sanitize=undefined` instead of adding to both: https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html#base-options

Answer (score 16):

I have installed `libubsan0` and `lib64ubsan0` and added `-lubsan` option, and my application compiled successfully!

Comment: I tried to add add_definitions("-fsanitize=undefined -lubsan") to my cmake, but still get the undefined reference error, even after installing the above two mentioned libraries, any ideas?

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: UBsan developers have always suggested (e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/address-sanitizer/SD590XDinfQ/NMUPj_G0BgAJ)) to avoid explicit `-lubsan`/`-lasan`/etc. and simply use `-fsanitize=undefined` both when compiling and linking code. One reason is that in case of clang UBSan runtime library consists of several different libraries with different names (not `libubsan.so`). Thus the underscore_d's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @yugr what should I do if my compile and link steps are separate? how can I pass "-fsanitize=undefined" to ld? I would have to just pass "-lubsan_lib.so" right? where ubsan_lib.so is a file I would download and put somewhere that ld can find it?

Comment: @ElliotGorokhovsky in general you should avoid explicit usage of `ld` (as it's not portable) and use gcc/clang driver for linking instead. To link with Asan/UBsan just add `-fsanitize=...` to `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: @yugr Thanks. Unfortunately I am trying to get this to work in a large project where the link step is separate from the compile step: https://zephyrproject.org/. Hopefully the LDFLAGS method will work.

Comment: @ElliotGorokhovsky that's interesting. In that case I suggest to run `gcc -v -fsanitize=...` on a dummy file and see what flags `ld` is run with. On my system it's `libasan_preinit.o --push-state --no-as-needed -lasan --pop-state` (I told you, it's ugly).

Comment: thanks, I'll try that and let you know what happens!